# SQL Case depending on previous status of record

Tags: sql, db2, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table containing status of a records. Something like this:

```
ID  STATUS  TIMESTAMP
1   I   01-01-2016
1   A   01-03-2016
1   P   01-04-2016
2   I   01-01-2016
2   P   01-02-2016
3   P   01-01-2016
```

I want to make a case where I take the newest version of each row, and for all P that has at some point been an I, they should be cased as a 'G' instead of P.

When I try to do something like

```
Select case when ID in (select ID from TABLE where ID = 'I') else ID END as     status) 
From TABLE
where ID in (select max(ID) from TABLE)
```

I get an error that this isn't possible using IN when casing.

So my question is, how do I do it then?

Want to end up with:

```
ID  STATUS  TIMESTAMP
1   G   01-04-2016
2   G   01-02-2016
3   P   01-01-2016
```

DBMS is IBM DB2

Comment: We are using IBM DB2 sql, if that is a DBMS?

Comment: You have not specified the exact DBMS

Comment: For each row? You mean for each ID? What's the expected result in case of a tie?

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table which returns each id with its newest timestamp. Join with that result:

```
select t1.ID, t1.STATUS, t1.TIMESTAMP
from tablename t1
join (select id, max(timestamp) as max_timestamp
      from tablename
      group by id) t2 
    ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.TIMESTAMP = t2.max_timestamp
```

Will return both rows in case of a tie (two rows with same newest timestamp.)

Note that ANSI SQL has `TIMESTAMP` as reserved word, so you may need to delimit it as `"TIMESTAMP"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a common table expression find all IDs that have had a status of `'I'`, and then using an outer join with your table to determine which IDs have had a status of `'I'` at some point.

To get the final result (with only the newest record) you can use the `row_number()` OLAP function and select only the "newest" record (this is shown in the `ranked` common table expression below:

```
with irecs (ID) as (
   select distinct
       ID
   from
       TABLE
   where
       status = 'I'
),
ranked as (
    select
        rownumber() over (partition by t.ID order by t.timestamp desc) as rn,
        t.id,
        case when i.id is null then t.status else 'G' end as status,
        t.timestamp
    from
        TABLE t
        left outer join irecs i
            on t.id = i.id
)
select 
    id, 
    status, 
    timestamp 
from 
    ranked 
where 
    rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select distinct f1.id, f4.*
from yourtable f1
inner join lateral 
(
   select 
   case (select count(*) from yourtable f3 where f3.ID=f2.ID and f3."TIMESTAMP"<f2."TIMESTAMP" and f3.STATUS='I')>0 then 'G' else f2.STATUS end as STATUS,
   f2."TIMESTAMP"
   from yourtable f2 where f2.ID=f3.ID
   order by f2."TIMESTAMP" desc, rrn(f2) desc
   fetch first rows only

) f4 on 1=1
```

rrn(f2) order is for same last date

ANSI SQL has TIMESTAMP as reserved word, so you may need to delimit it as "TIMESTAMP"

Answer (score 0):

other solution

```
with youtableranked as (
select f1.id, 
case (select count(*) from yourtable f2 where f2.ID=f1.ID and f2."TIMESTAMP"<f1."TIMESTAMP" and f2.STATUS='I')>0 then 'G' else f1.STATUS end as STATUS,
rownumber() over(partition by f1.id order by f1.TIMESTAMP desc, rrn(f1) desc) rang,
f1."TIMESTAMP"
from yourtable f1
)
select * from youtableranked f0
where f0.rang=1
```

ANSI SQL has TIMESTAMP as reserved word, so you may need to delimit it as "TIMESTAMP"